# C#, filter custom attribute property values

Tags: c#, linq, attributes, filtering

Consider a class:

```
    public class Dog
    {
        [Key]
        [TableField(Name= "Jersey", Inoculated = false)]
        public string Param1{ get; set; }

        [TableField(Name= "Daisy", Inoculated = true)]
        public string Param2{ get; set; }

        [TableField(Name= "Jeremy", Inoculated = true)]
        public string Param3{ get; set; }
    }
```

And an attribute class:

```
    public sealed class TableField : Attribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Inoculated { get; set; }
    }
```

This is a bit far from real-life example but what I need is to select all TableField.Name property values from typeof(Dog) (default class value)  where TableField.Inoculated == true.

Best attempt, don't know where to go from here:

```
var names = typeof(Dog).GetProperties()
    .Where(r => r.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableField), false).Cast<TableField>()
    .Any(x => x.Inoculated));
```

Comment: Are you asking for `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueriable<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select from properties by attributes, the following example may be useful to you.

```
var dogType = typeof(Dog);
var names = dogType.GetProperties()
                .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(TableField)))
                .Select(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<TableField>())
                .Where(x => x.Inoculated == true)
                .Select(x=>x.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using System.Reflection, you could do something like this:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetDogNames()
    {
        var namesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var props = typeof(Dog).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (object attr in attrs)
            {
                if (attr is TableField tableField && tableField.Inoculated)
                {
                    string propName = prop.Name;
                    string auth = tableField.Name;

                    namesDict.Add(propName, auth);
                }
            }
        }

        return namesDict;
    }
```